Kafka streams rate limit - threads starvation
I try to achieve kafka streams with rate limiting functionality,
I use kafka-streams-3.4.1 and spring-kafka-3.0.13
And when I use something blocking inside pipeline, like
 streamsBuilder.stream(streamProps.topicFrom())
                .process(() -> new RateLimitingProcessor<>(rateLimiterRegistry))
                .to(streamProps.topicTo());

and
@Override
public void process(Record<K, V> inputRecord) {
    context().recordMetadata().ifPresentOrElse(
            recordMetadata -> {
                String topic = recordMetadata.topic();
                limitersRegistry.getLimiter(topic).ifPresent(limiter -> {
                    while (!limiter.acquirePermission()) {}
                });
               
                context().forward(inputRecord.withHeaders(inputRecord.headers()));
            },
            () -> log.error("Record metadata is absent, cannot limit rate")
    );
}

in my ContextualProcessor, I encounter something like threads starvation,
All the threads from my

num.stream.threads

do attempt to process this records and getting stuck there,
meanwhile other pipelines (without rate limiters) are dead and left unprocessed,
Is there a way to implement something like this?
May be 'one thread per topic' behaviour?
I don't want all my threads to process same blocked pipeline.
Thank you!

at the moment, the only solution I found - is declaring new Topology + and then start new KafkaStreams object for each and every limited topic, not sure if it's correct.
I think spring's streamBuilder uses same topology and same KafkaStreams object,
so same threads process all the tasks from all declared pipelines
